# Regex to isolate urls but not emails

Tags: regex

I'm really new to regex but I have a work assignment that requires me to complete the following task and it's driving me crazy. Any help would be appreciated

I have to filter posts into a chat to censor all links, except for emails, using regex. So far I have the following which seems to work for most forms of URL but its also catching emails.

```
([--:\w?%&+~#=]*\.[a-z]{2,4}\/{0,2})((?:[?&](?:\w+)=(?:\w+))+|[--:\w?@%&+~#=]+)?
```

Here is a link, showing my problem: https://regexr.com/3tg56

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs and the expected output?

Comment: http://example.com
https://example.com
www.example.com
http://www.example.com would all be caught, even within a sentence, like:

Come visit me at http://example.com for a great time!

But the above regex is also catching the domain part of email address's

paul@somemail.com is being selected due to somemail.com

I hope this explains things a little better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to lookbehind for a space (or the beginning of the line):

```
(?<= |^)([--:\w?%&+~#=]*\.[a-z]{2,4}\/{0,2})((?:[?&](?:\w+)=(?:\w+))+|[--:\w?@%&+~#=]+)?
^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/upBNT0/1

Comment: You need to enable the multiline flag so that the `^` can match the beginning of a line. https://regexr.com/3tg59

Comment: I think this actually works!! Thanks you!! (sorry about the multiline flag, I really am EXTREMELY new to Regex)

Comment: Is there a way this can be made to allow facebook urls?

Comment: Add negative lookahead for non-space characters followed by `facebook` : `(?!\S*facebook)` https://regex101.com/r/upBNT0/3

Comment: THANK YOU @CertainPerformance ... you really are amazingly helpful!!

Comment: hey there @CertainPerformance is there anyway to modify this to ignore multiple occurances of "."? As things like
_hello..ddfddfd
hello...dadasdsada
hello ...dfdsfs
hello.. sdfdsfds
hello......dsfsdfds_
Are all being filtered out at the moment lol. I'd appreciate your help if you can spare the time to look?

Thanks, in advance :)

Comment: The character range at the beginning `--:` is including periods, so you might just remove that part `[\w?`... https://regex101.com/r/upBNT0/4 or, include everything in that range *except* a period, if there's a reason for it